# Cannot change mobile network Sony Xperia V

Tags: sony-xperia, mobile-network, network-signal, sony-xperia-v

I have a **Xperia V** device which worked fine until few days ago. I still use 3G SIM, and I've enabled WCDMA(preffered)/GSM from settings menu *(Settings->More>Mobile Networks->Network Mode)*. This works perfectly fine until few days ago. I usually get 3G signal, rarely 2G.

One day suddenly I found that phone with no mobile network connection. I thought maybe something wrong with signal coverage. But it didn't changed even after I changed my location. I has few options in Network Mode menu as follows,

- WCDMA only
- GSM only
- WCDMA(preffered)/GSM
- LTE(preffered)WCDMA//GSM

If I choose anything with WCDMA, phone gets disconnected from the carrier and I can only use the option *GSM only* whyich gets the connection.

I haven't updated or rooted or did anything to the phone recently.

I tried restarting the phone, toggle flight mode , remove and re-insert the sim card but nothing works.

1. Why can't I connect to WCDMA/3G?
2. Why am I only able to connect to 2G network?

This happens in every scenario.not on when turn on mobile data connection. I lost signal when I try to connect to any option other than *GSM only*

Comment: Verify that the APN settings (in mobile networks) is correct with the carrier.

Comment: @Bo Lawson, What the APN settings have to do with signal lost? Or what setting OP need to check ?

Comment: @esQmo_ Really just a step in troubleshooting data issues. I was thinking it had to do with the loss of 3g and only being able to access 2g networks. Maybe the carrier changed them and his phone did not get the updated APN.

Comment: @BoLawson It's not related to mobile data connection, but no mobile network connectivity. How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe the settings of changing network are not sticking as they should. Try lower level stuff as explained here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189727/131553

Comment: @beeshyams same output happens. when I choose WCDMA only, signals get dropped. same as above. I don't know what to do now

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to take backup, factory reset and flash your ROM or the updated version. If that doesn't help, head to service center

Comment: @beeshyams are you suggesting that this could be a hardware problem?

Comment: Suggesting a way to trouble shoot. If first part of suggestion works, fine else it may well be hardware

Comment: Also check the network operators in /settings/mobile data/settings/mobile networks/network operators. Next, try to manually set the network with search network then select the proper network I.E. t-mobile wcdma or whatever.

Comment: @BoLawson when I try that, I can see both 2G and 3G networks available on my carrier, but when I try to register on 3G network, it displays an error message saying unable to register, make sure sim is inserted and supports the selected network