# Moto e2 doesn't recognise mobile network, what can I do?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-data

My wife has recently switched mobile operator and now can't get mobile data. Phone calls and text are OK. WiFi is OK.

Going to Settings -> More -> Mobile Networks -> Network Operators shows a list of possible networks (The usual UK ones: EE, Vodafone etc) but not the one she's with. We've been through the APN settings and they are identical to the settings on my phone, which works.

If we turn the phone off and on again, or switch it into airplane mode and back again we get the following message:

> You have lost data connectivity because you left your home network with data roaming turned off.

I have no idea what this message means.

The operator piggybacks on EE and the name at the top left says "EE - plusnet", but there is an "R" over the mobile signal strength indicator - which we've worked out means "roaming".

I'm also with Plusnet and if we swap sims hers works properly in my phone but mine still shows the "R". This make me think it's something wrong with the phone itself.

The phone is a Moto E<sup>2</sup> on Android 6.0 Marshmallow. It had no problem with mobile data on the previous carrier (giff-gaff).

We haven't tried a factory reset of the phone yet.

Other than that, is there anything we can do to get the phone to recognise the correct network?

Comment: See if this helps https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189727/131553

Comment: From phone info tab( after foaling the code) try enable data

Comment: @beeshyams I'll look into that, but I think the problem is that our network doesn't appear in that list.