# How to forbid/ block Android from connecting to a certain phone provider

Tags: mobile-data, roaming

I need a way to block my phone from connecting to AT&T since my service provider in Canada only has a roaming plan in the US that uses T-mobile's network. I can force my phone to lock onto T-mobile while I'm roaming in the US, but then I need to change this back to my Canadian provider when i cross back into Canada. I cross daily, so this is a royal PIA. It's a 50/50 chance which provider it decides to connect to when I cross into the US. Would be great if a developer could write a script that allows the user to exclude certain networks to be connected to in Automatic mode.

Comment: The SIM card you use is configured by your provider and usually it only connects to networks where the provider has a roaming contract with. Thus I would contact your provider and complain about that the SIM card chooses the wrong network.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There are existing questions related to your issue: [Stop auto-selecting cellular network](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189450/44325). Consider reading the answers there and let us know the result. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions, both require two sims, one for each country.

1. Get two phones with individual sims and block roaming.
2. Get a dual sim phone and stop roaming.  Every time you cross the border, disable the other sim.