# How to really enable manual carrier selection on Android?

Tags: settings

On Android settings it is possible to disable the automatic carrier selection. However, the functionality doesn't seem to work properly since as soon there is no reception for the chosen carrier, it will automatically connect to another carrier, causing extra changes when roaming. How to **actually** enable manual carrier selection on Android?

Comment: This may help https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189727/131553

Comment: Whats wrong with disabling roaming ?